# does swift 4 need a main class to run or not ? and when should i use a class to run my code?

Tags: swift, swift4

```
import Foundation

func diagonalDifference(arr: [[Int]]) -> Int {



}

let stdout = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["OUTPUT_PATH"]!
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: stdout, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: stdout)!

guard let n = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
else { fatalError("Bad input") }

let arr: [[Int]] = AnyIterator{ readLine() }.prefix(n).map {
    let arrRow: [Int] = $0.split(separator: " ").map {
        if let arrItem = Int($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)) {
            return arrItem
        } else { fatalError("Bad input") }
    }

    guard arrRow.count == n else { fatalError("Bad input") }

    return arrRow
}

guard arr.count == n else { fatalError("Bad input") }

let result = diagonalDifference(arr: arr)

fileHandle.write(String(result).data(using: .utf8)!)
fileHandle.write("\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
```

I just want to know ,is there any main function in swift like java which run first? and How should i scan a line or int in swift through console?

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Comment: to scan input from console you can use `readLine`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641199-readline

Comment: About `main` function.. Did you use a playground?

Comment: If your code is working, then clearly a main class is not needed. If it's not working, what problems do you experience?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/511-command-line-programs-on-macos-tutorial) article could be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of `readLine` usage to scan console input (the function from the Swift Standard Library)

```
let userInput = readLine()
```

It returns an optional value (`String?`)